# How Java program can tell if an object from an array is pulled

Tags: java

As part of a programming project I am attempting to program a simple game of Slapjack (simple because there is no way the player can lose). I have a card class, a deck class, and a main class. For the most part everything works, the deck shuffles, I can deal out cards, etc. Since it is Slapjack I need the program to know when a Jack is dealt, however I have no idea how to make that happen. The Program is as follows:

**Card Class**

```
public class Card2
{
private int rank, suit;
private static String[] suits = { "hearts", "spades", "diamonds", "clubs" };
private static String[] ranks  = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" };

public String toString()
{
      return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit];
}
public int getRank() 
{
     return rank;
}
public int getSuit()
{
    return suit;
}

Card2 (int suit, int rank)
{
    this.rank=rank;
    this.suit=suit;
}
}
```

**Deck Class**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck2
{
private Card2[] cards;
int i;
Deck2()
{
    i=51;
    cards = new Card2[52];
    int x=0;
    for (int a=0; a<=3; a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<=12; b++)
         {
           cards[x] = new Card2(a,b);
           x++;
         }
    }
}

public Card2 Draw()
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    int index=0;

    do {
        index = generator.nextInt( 52 );
    } while (cards[index] == null);
    i--;
    Card2 temp = cards[index];
    cards[index]= null;
    return temp;
}

public int getTotal()
{
    return i;
}
}
```

**Main Program**

```
public class Main2
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Deck2 deck = new Deck2();

    System.out.println (deck.Draw());
}
}
```

Comment: _" Since it is Slapjack I need the program to know when a Jack is dealt"_. Have you made an attempts at this?

Comment: Where do you pull the object from the array? Which operation does that? You simply have to store the selected object from the array in another array for example, that would keep a list of dealt items

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, *please* follow java naming conventions: name your methods with a leading lowercase letter.

To see if a jack was drawn, keep a reference to the drawn card:

```
Card card = deck.Draw();
if (card.getRank() == 9) {
    // the card drawn was a jack
}
```

Comment: As he currently has it, this will not compile, let alone run.  "getRank()" returns an int.

Comment: @MadConan didn't even check that. Fixed, but even more brittle now :/

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework, so I'm not going to give you the full solution.  I will give you a big hint:  `getRank()` isn't doing what it should do.  As you currently have it coded, it returns the index of the ranks, not an actual rank.

EDIT: I see the single constructor ensures the rank and suit are initialized properly so I deleted my statement about the potential `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.